# Compile Error Source option no longer supported

Tags: gcc, javac

ERROR:

```
K:~$ ./compile_all
warning: [options] bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 1.3
error: Source option 1.3 is no longer supported. Use 7 or later.
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/cco1N9ku.o: in function `splitDouble':
slalom.c:(.text+0xfd): undefined reference to `floor'
/usr/bin/ld: slalom.c:(.text+0x209): undefined reference to `floor'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/cco1N9ku.o: in function `chunkDoubleMag':
slalom.c:(.text+0x818): undefined reference to `floor'
/usr/bin/ld: slalom.c:(.text+0x884): undefined reference to `floor'
/usr/bin/ld: slalom.c:(.text+0x8dd): undefined reference to `floor'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/cco1N9ku.o:slalom.c:(.text+0x91c): more undefined references to `floor' follow
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/cco1N9ku.o: in function `setLength':
slalom.c:(.text+0x1538): undefined reference to `sqrt'
```

I am trying to run the program from this source https://mcbilliards.sourceforge.net/readme.php. My compiler versions javac 17.0.9 and gcc (Ubuntu 11.4.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 11.4.0. The following error occurs and I don't understand how to correct it. I assume that different compiler versions are needed.

Please help me fix the error.